# How can I stop find from searching after first result found?

Tags: find

I am using 'find' to get the path to a dir called "out" and want it to stop looking after it is found.  There can be some 350G worth of files in that dir so I REALLY want it to stop looking once it is found.

This works bu doesn't stop looking, takes too long..

```
find . -type d -name out
```

This "ungreedy" approach also works but doesn't seem to stop either...

```
find . -type d -regex ".+/out/?"
```

I'm running this in perl, so I suppose I could write a recursive function that reads down a dir tree and does what I want.  But is there a brake in "find" that I can apply once the first instance is found?

Thanks in Advance !

Comment: check this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62880/how-to-stop-the-find-command-after-first-match

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `-quit`:

```
find . -type d -name out -print -quit
```

Manual for "find" tool is [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html).

Comment: It doesn't work for me (on Mac) but `-print -quit` does!

Comment: true, I missied `-print`